# Big O of get largest Numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Got this question recently:

Write a function which takes an array of arrays (each of which contains numbers sorted from largest to smallest), and a number (n). Return the n largest numbers.

For example:

findLargest([ [10, 5, 3, 1], [9, 8, 7, 6], [11, 2, 1, 0] ], 5) 
=> [11, 10, 9, 8, 7]

findLargest([ [15, 5, 3, 1], [10, 8, 7, 6]], 3)
=> [ 15, 10, 8 ]

Do this without copying or modifying the arrays (just read from them).
Optimize for time complexity.

I came up with this, but am not that happy with my solution:

```
function findLargest(numberArrays, n ) {
  var results = [];
  var pointers = [];

  for (var x = 0; x < numberArrays.length; x++) {
    pointers.push(0);
  }

  while (results.length < n) {
    var subMaxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pointers.length; i++) {
      var point = pointers[i];
      subMaxes.push(numberArrays[i][point]);
    }
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, subMaxes);
    var indexOfMax = subMaxes.indexOf(max);
    pointers[indexOfMax]++;
    results.push(max);  
  }
  return results;
}
```

I think it is O(n^2).... is there anyway to do it in O(n)?

Comment: It depends on whether you feel like "n" is the number of arrays, or number of total elements in all arrays. _Given that individual arrays themselves are already sorted_, you can probably do _better_ than "n" in terms of number of elements, but may need n log n in terms of number of arrays.

Comment: It's dependent on the number of items in the arrays.

Comment: The complexity is the number of arrays times the number of elements on the longest array.

Comment: This probably better for CodeReview SE

Answer (score 1):

The question can be formalised (and slightly tweaked) as, `Given a 2D array of dimension n x n, where each row is sorted in a decreasing order, find the largest k elements`

For the largest `n` elements, the time complexity will be `O(nlogn)`. The procedure for `k` largest elements is explained below:

- Build a max heap of the first element from each row: Time complexity is O(n)
- Extract the largest element from the heap, and insert an element into the heap from the row to which the extracted element belongs. Time Complexity is O(logn)
- Repeat under desired number of elements is extracted.

So an iteration to extract the largest number requires O(logn) time, with a pre-processing O(n) cost.

To extract `k` elements, the time complexity of the above algorithm is `O(klogn)`

Comment: Extraction of the largest number is constant because it is at the top of the heap, no? The insertions are what causes the `O(logn)`

Comment: How would you implement this without modifying the arrays? I used an index to keep track of where I was in each array. How do you do the part in step 2--- "insert an element into the heap from the row to which the extracted element belongs"--- how does one keep reference to which one it belonged to?

Comment: @WinchenzoMagnifico : By having your heap use pair<int,int> where the first is the value of the object and the second is the index of the row to which it belongs.

Comment: @cricket_007 : You are correct. I combined that into one step and wrote it as such. But to be precise, accessing the top element from the heap is `O(1)`, but removing it will be `O(logn)` as you need to rearrange the heap.

Answer (score 0):

1. Merge all arrays into single array.  This takes O(n) time.
2. Use median of medians algorithm to find kth largest element in new array. O(n) time.
3. Traverse array and grab all elements greater than or equal to that element.  This takes O(n) time.

This algorithm runs in O(n) time.